# Updating several lines of a csv

Tags: c#

I am trying to update a CSV file with data from a textbox and running into issues.

**Example CSV:**
test1,data1,moredata1
test2,data2,moredata2
test3,data3,moredata3
test4,data4,moredata4
test5,data5,moredata5
test6,data6,moredata6
test7,data7,moredata7
test8,data8,moredata8
test9,data9,moredata9
test10,data10,moredata10

**Expected CSV:**
test1,Change1,moredata1
test2,data2,moredata2
test3,data3,moredata3
test4,Change2,moredata4
test5,data5,moredata5
test6,data6,moredata6
test7,data7,moredata7
test8,data8,moredata8
test9,data9,moredata9
test10,Change3,moredata10

**Actual CSV**

```
test1,Change1
,moredata1
test2,data2,moredata2
test3,data3,moredata3
test4,data4,moredata4
test5,data5,moredata5
test6,data6,moredata6
test7,data7,moredata7
test8,data8,moredata8
test9,data9,moredata9
test10,data10,moredata10
test1,Change1
,moredata1
test2,data2,moredata2
test3,data3,moredata3
test4,Change2
,moredata4
test5,data5,moredata5
test6,data6,moredata6
test7,data7,moredata7
test8,data8,moredata8
test9,data9,moredata9
test10,data10,moredata10
test1,Change1
,moredata1
test2,data2,moredata2
test3,data3,moredata3
test4,data4,moredata4
test5,data5,moredata5
test6,data6,moredata6
test7,data7,moredata7
test8,data8,moredata8
test9,data9,moredata9
test10,Change3,moredata10
test1,Change1
,moredata1
test2,data2,moredata2
test3,data3,moredata3
test4,Change2
,moredata4
test5,data5,moredata5
test6,data6,moredata6
test7,data7,moredata7
test8,data8,moredata8
test9,data9,moredata9
test10,Change3,moredata10
```

**Code:**

```
var importboxData = massimportBox.Text.Split('\n');
                foreach (var iLine in importboxData)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
                    {
                        String line;

                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (line.Split(',')[0].Equals(iLine.Split(',')[0]))
                            {
                                String[] split = line.Split(',');
                                int indexNum = Int32.Parse(indexBox.Text);

                                split[indexNum] = iLine.Split(',')[1];
                                line = String.Join(",", split);
                            }
                            lines.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
                    {
                        foreach (String line in lines)
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
```

**Form:**
[image]

**Using updated code from Answer:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unnecessarily reading and writing the whole file for every single desired change.

Try something more like:

```
Dictionary<String, String> changes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (String iLine in massimportBox.Lines)
{
    String[] values = iLine.Split(',');
    if (values.Length==2 && values[0].Trim().Length>0)
    {
        changes[values[0]] = values[1];
    }
}

int indexNum = Int32.Parse(indexBox.Text);

String[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
for (int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
{
    String[] values = lines[i].Split(',');
    String key = values[0];
    if (changes.ContainsKey(key) && indexNum>=0 && indexNum<values.Length)
    {
        values[indexNum] = changes[key];
        lines[i] = String.Join(",", values);
    }
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that worked exactly like expected! Quick question, what is the line values.Lenth==2~ doing?

Comment: `values.Length==2` is making sure there are EXACTLY two parts on the line; the "key" before the comma, and the "value" after the comma. If there aren't two parts then we won't know what to replace the old value with.

Comment: Got ya, ok! One other issue. So it seemed to work, kinda. It seems to be messing up the spacing however. I posted a screenshot in top post.

Comment: You're writing a TEXT FILE, which has absolutely NO notion of spacing when opened in Excel. Make those columns BIGGER with your mouse!  You can't control the sizing of the "columns" with this approach. If you want to control what the data would look like in Excel, then you need to be creating a `.xlsx` file, not a `.txt` CSV file.  Creating an actual Excel spreadsheet would be way harder...

Comment: It is not a spacing issue, that was poor wording on my part. They are in completely new cells. Example, before running the code, test2 was in A1. After running code, it is now in A3 and A2 is blank. Viewing the .csv file via notepad.exe shows everything normal, but trying to run a application to parse the .csv is failing now. -- EDIT: It has to be something with splitting the textbox with '\n'. Because when just doing a single line, everything is fine.

Comment: If you think it's the TextBox parsing, change `foreach (String iLine in massimportBox.Text.Split('\n'))` to `foreach (String iLine in massimportBox.Lines)` and see if that behaves any better.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with nested loops. Your code will repeat the file reading once for each requested change. Try the following solution where a dictionary of <key, cahnge> values ​​is created and the file is read once.

```cs
var importboxData = massimportBox.Text.Split('\n');
Dictionary<string,string> iSplitDict = new Dictionary<string,string> ()
foreach (var iLine in importboxData)
{
    string[] iSplit = iLine.Split(',');
    iSplitDict.Add(iSplit[0], iSplit[1])
}

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] split = line.Split(',');
        if (iSplitDict.ContainsKey(split[0]))
        {
            int indexNum = Int32.Parse(indexBox.Text);
            split[indexNum] = iSplitDict[split[0]];
            line = String.Join(",", split);
        }
        lines.Add(line);
    }

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
    {
        foreach (String line in lines)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```